# Python, invoke method returned by __getattribute__

Tags: python, methods, metaprogramming

*If this question has a duplicate, sorry, I didn't find it, I will erese the question if someone does.*

I have this simple python class:

```
class NothingSpecial:
     @classmethod
     def meth(cls): 
          print("hi!")
```

And trying to get the method with different ways I did:

```
a = (object.__getattribute__(NothingSpecial, 'meth'))

b = (getattr(NothingSpecial, 'meth'))
```

The question is, if I do:

```
b()
```

> $hi!

Is return, but when I do:

```
a()
```

> TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable

How can I execute the `a` method?

Comment: Why are you using `object.__getattribute__`, anyway? That's the wrong `__getattribute__`.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm using it because I'm trying to fully understand how it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are bypassing the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and you have an unbound class method.

The solution is to invoke the protocol, if there is a [`__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) present:

```
if hasattr(a, '__get__'):
    a = a.__get__(None, NothingSpecial)
a()
```

Now the classmethod is bound to the class and it works again:

```
>>> a.__get__(None, NothingSpecial)
<bound method NothingSpecial.meth of <class '__main__.NothingSpecial'>>
>>> a.__get__(None, NothingSpecial)()
hi!
```

Alternatively, use the *correct* `__getattribute__`, one that actually knows how to apply the descriptor protocol to class attributes; classes do not use `object.__getattribute__`, but `type.__getattribute__`:

```
>>> type.__getattribute__(NothingSpecial, 'meth')
<bound method NothingSpecial.meth of <class '__main__.NothingSpecial'>>
```

You'd actually want to access `type(NothingSpecial).__getattribute__` to allow metaclasses to override the implementation of `__getattribute__` here.

Comment: Why the first parameter is None? I mean, I tryed and it worked, but all of it is a little new to me, sorry if the question are a little basics

Comment: So, why is `NothingSpecial.__getattribute__` inherited from `object` when `isinstance(NothingSpecial, type)`?

Comment: @DamianLattenero: the first argument is for an *instance*, but you have a class here, not an instance.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: that's the method used for instances. Special methods are always looked up on the type, see [*Special Method Lookup*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think I'm start understanding, thanks a lot, plus one for great answer. In a few minutes I will accept

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: so `type(instance).__getattribute__(instance, attrname)` will find `object.__getattribute__`. `type(ClassObject).__getattribute__(ClassObject, attrname)` is `type.__getattribute__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters aha, thank you. Certainly this is a piece of arcana, but it makes sense.